# How to send email form Angular v15 using @sendgrid/mail?

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript, sendgrid

I am trying to send an email from Angular v15 using @sendgrid; However, I am getting the errors below on importing the dependencies like : import { MailService } from "@sendgrid/mail";

I don't know if @sendgrid supports later versions of angular or not.

```
Cannot find module 'https' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import * as https from 'https';
```

Anyone can help will be appreciated.

I installed the required dependencies like:

```
npm install @sendgrid/mail,
npm i @types/node
```

I was expecting to be able to send email template from Angular v15.
I don't know why its not working through or with angular. I even tried to get help from ChatGPT but no success.

On the other hand, I tested to use Node.js without angular to send the email and surprisingly it works and I was able to receive the email.

```
require("dotenv").config();

const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");

sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

const sendMail = async (msg) => {
  try {
    await sgMail.send(msg);
    console.log("Message sent successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);

    if (error.response) {
      console.error(error.response.body);
    }
  }
};

sendMail({
  to: "xyz@gmail.com",
  from: "ptj@hotmail.com",
  subject: "Hello Test",
  html: `<p style="font-weight: 600; background-color: #ff0000">Hello This is test email</p>`,
});
```

Comment: I misspelled the Question. It should be "How to send email from Angular v15 using @sendgrid/mail?"

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend to use Angular like this, remember that Angular is a frontend framework with Server Side Rendering with Angular Universal

On the server side only is recommended to generate rendered content, not to do another tasks, and send a email on the frontend, is expose your secrets to everyone and expose your secret methods to everyone

For these kind of tasks is recommended to build a backend application / API and call these APIs from the front end

So on the front side you should make a http post call, for example, and on the server side in the API application, execute the methods with sendgrid

There are a lot of Javascript/Typescript backend frameworks to do this, like NestJS, Loopback, Express...

Good luck!